# Table formatting woes in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Please forgive my all-encompassing ignorance, but I just can't get my table to look right in my webform.

I declare a table:

```
<table>
</table>
```

and it has no border. There is an attribute for border, as such:

```
<table border="1">
</table>
```

but asp.net tells me that the border attribute is 'obsolete'.
I try to add it in CSS...

```
.table{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
```

...but this just puts a border around the whole table, not the individual cells.

All I want is a normal looking table with lines around each cell. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
table, table th, table td { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
```

(need to apply the border to the table-cells too)

Answer (score 1):

The code above won't work as...

```
.table{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
```

is looking for a class of "table" and not a table element. Either update the table class to "table"...

```
<table class="table">
```

...or change your CSS to find the table element itself.

```
table{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }
```

You will also need to style `th` and `td` elements to have the border.